# How to get the final status of an outbound Twilio call in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, twilio

I have a .NET console app that is generating calls and I need to take action based on whether or not the call was answered.  The call is successful, I answer it on my test cellphone and I hear the speech from my xml file.  The status of the CallResource object, however, is always "queued".  What is the proper way to get the final status of the call?

Code:

```
Dim phonecall = CallResource.Create([to]:=New Types.PhoneNumber(oncallnumber), from:=New Types.PhoneNumber(twilionumber), url:=New Uri(oncallmessagefile), method:="get")
Dim OnCallStatus As CallResource.StatusEnum

'' wait until the call is successful, not answered, or fails
Do
    OnCallStatus = phonecall.Status
    Debug.WriteLine(OnCallStatus.ToString)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
Loop Until OnCallStatus = CallResource.StatusEnum.NoAnswer Or OnCallStatus = CallResource.StatusEnum.Completed Or OnCallStatus = CallResource.StatusEnum.Failed
```

Comment: i think you have to call the service again. i dont see that happening in your code.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Do I need to call a method on the exsting CallResource object or create a new CallResource object?

Comment: it depends - where did you get call resource from?

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, thank you!  I need to call CallResource.Fetch() and pass the SID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an approach that works:

```
Dim phonecall = CallResource.Create([to]:=New Types.PhoneNumber(oncallnumber), from:=New Types.PhoneNumber(twilionumber), url:=New Uri(oncallmessagefile), method:="get")
Dim sid As String = phonecall.Sid
Dim OnCallStatus As CallResource.StatusEnum

'' wait until the call is successful, not answered, or fails
Do
    OnCallStatus = CallResource.Fetch(sid).Status
    Debug.WriteLine(Now() & " - " & OnCallStatus.ToString)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
Loop Until OnCallStatus = CallResource.StatusEnum.NoAnswer Or OnCallStatus = CallResource.StatusEnum.Completed Or OnCallStatus = CallResource.StatusEnum.Failed
```